# Trigger on Lead History Object

Tags: apex, trigger

Can we write the trigger on Lead History Object? Actually, I want to migrate the Data of Lead History to a Custom Object and me don't want to use batch for the Same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, trigger on LeadHistory object is not available from Salesforce.

You can write a Apex Batch to query LeadHistory records and put those into Custom Object.